# Renderizar varias queries en Node Express

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, mysqlconnector

Estoy trabajando con Node.js (express) y MySQL y he tenido problemas al intentar hacer varias consultas en una misma ruta. El error que lanza es:

> Can't set headers after they are sent.

Y el código es este:

```
router.post('/test', function (req, res, next){
db.query("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 
TABLE_NAME = 'registros';", function (error, results, fields) {

if (error) throw error;
res.render('test', {
    columnNames: results
  });});
db.query("SELECT * FROM registros", function (error, resp, fields) {

if (error) throw error;
res.render('test', {
    dataRegistros: resp
  });});

});
```

Entiendo que puede ser porque está renderizando dos veces en la misma ruta. ¿Cuál sería el método correcto para hacer varias consultas SQL y devolverlas a un archivo en view?

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> De acuerdo con el controlador mysql nodejs, puede configurarlo o combinar ?>las consultas y devolver una matriz con resultados
>
> Debe configurar esto cuando crea la conexión:

```
mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

> A continuación, realice la solicitud con ambas consultas

```
router.post('/test', function (req, res, next) {

var queries = [
"select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 
'registros'",
"SELECT * FROM registros"
];

db.query(queries.join(';'), function (error, results, fields) {

if (error) throw error;

res.render('test', {
  columnNames: results[0], // First query from array
  dataRegistros: resp      // Second query from array
});

});

});
```

Esto funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes anidar tus callbacks (Si son solo 2 aún es legible).

```
router.post('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    db.query("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'registros'; ", (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        db.query("SELECT * FROM registros", (error, resp, fields) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            res.render('test', {
                dataRegistros: resp,
                columnNames: results
            });
        });
    });
});
```